# Linear approximation of modular addition of a constant?

Tags: cryptanalysis, linear-cryptanalysis, arx

In [Linear Approximations of Additions Modulo $2^n$](https://iacr.org/archive/fse2003/28870277/28870277.pdf), Wallén shows how to compute the correlation of the modular addition of two binary bit vectors. A simple recursive procedure was given by Schulte-Geers in [On CCZ-equivalence of Addition mod $2^n$](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00607747/document). However, these papers both assume that the summands are uniformly distributed random variables over $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Suppose one has $f: \mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2^n$, $f(x) = x \boxplus C$, where $C \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ is fixed, and $\boxplus$ means modular addition. If $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ are bitmasks, and juxtaposition means bitwise $\operatorname{AND}$, what can one say about the bias of the approximation $\langle \alpha x, \beta f(x)\rangle = 0$?